# Graph API SEARCH not returning public posts done on a page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, search, post, hashtag

I'm trying to get posts with a certain keyword (in fact, a hashtag), but I'm not receiving all posts. For example, there are a lot of posts done by users on a certain page that are not being pulled although they're public. The call I do is similar to this one:

https://graph.facebook.com/search?type=post&q=keyword&access_token=XXXXX

Not sure if this type of posts are considered public but only retrievable by specifying the page:

https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID/feed?access_token=XXXXX

But I need to retrieve all public posts containing a certain keyword and I don't know exactly which pages could users post to with this hashtag...

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that Facebook has just taken down public post search in Graph API v2.0 so you won't be available to do that anymore.

Check https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading under section Graph API "Public post search is no longer available. (/search?type=post&q=foobar)"

Comment: Oh, thank you very much! I can't believe that they're taking down this feature... As Facebook has hashtags but people is not able to search by using them!